# Iteration limit 10000 is reached

Tags: verilog

i am using the following code.

```
    `timescale 1ns / 1ps
module program_counter
    (
    input        clock,
    input       reset,
    input [31:0]     in,
    output reg [31:0] out
    );
        initial 
            begin
                out <= 32'b00000000000000000000000000000001;
            end
    always @(negedge clock)
        begin
            if(reset)
                begin
                    out <= 32'b00000000000000000000000000000001;
                end
            else
                begin
                    out <= in;
                end
        end
endmodule
```

It is showing error as shown

> "ERROR: at 0 ps: Iteration limit 10000 is reached. Possible zero delay oscillation detected where simulation can not advance in time because signals can not resolve to a stable value in File "C:/dewesh/latest_bkup/Program_counter.v" Line 12. Please correct this code in order to advance past the current simulation time."

I am not able to find what is the problem.

Comment: `32'b00000000000000000000000000000001;` is the same as `32'b1;`

Comment: 32'h**** is shorter one for you. If you want to demical, assign it as 1, 32bit is suitable for int.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the first line in initial is *zero* delay. This should be driven at time 0. Try placing a delay on the initial (#1).

You also look to be mixing synthesizable and non-synthesizable code in the one module. This is probably not what you want.

Get rid of the initial block from *this* module and instantiate this module with a test bench which has the time scale and which drives the inputs to this module, with appropriate delays.